# NGINX, Include in my virtual host file

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a DV server with MediaTemple and recently had their support enable ngnix webserver. I have been integrating their ProCDN with Super Cache on the WordPress sites on the DV.

I noticed on this domain convoyofhope.eu that the CDN is working properly, but if you view the site on Firefox the fontface isn´t working because of the cross-domain issue. I found this site that seems to solve the problem http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default

My question is, in the site it says:

Also, if you are using nginx as your webserver you will need to include the code below in your virtual host file:

```
location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

I am just not sure where I put this on my server. I checked the vhost for convoyofhope.eu but I didn´t see where I would add that to make this work. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It would generally go in the nginx configuration file that has the `server` block for that host:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  convoyofhope.eu;

    ...
    location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
    ...
}
```

On RHEL related distributions, this would be on the file system somewhere under `/etc/nginx/`. Your particular distribution may vary.

Comment: When I do access vhost /convoyofhope.eu / conf / there are two files with time stamps, but on top of both files it says this: #ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

Comment: @Stacker - That is where the location directive goes. You may have to talk to your provider about how to get the generator program to add the block.

Comment: I was on with support with them and the guy I had talked to wasn´t too helpful and said I needed to come here actually :) I can try again too with them.

Comment: I was told by MT to find the solution here http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?260814-Nginx-configuration-for-vhosts, which states: http://pastebin.com/jdag6uC0 so the code that is in that file is this: http://pastebin.com/YsFzW20f, just not sure how I enter the code above in that file :)

Comment: @Stacker - sorry, I can only help with nginx. I don't know Plesk, and I don't know PHP. Your hosting company really should be giving you more help with this. If they cannot help, I would seriously consider looking for a new provider.

Answer (score 0):

On MediaTemple, in your Plesk control panel, go to Websites & Domains (tab) -> Web Server Settings then scroll down to "Additional nginx directives". Place your location… directive in the text box there.